# Linux Bash Input

Tags: linux, bash, input, communication

Have a question about linux bash. I want to start a program and then send input to it.
Normally in de terminal I do just, `./chat` and then type something.

I dont know how it should be in bash, i tried this:

`./chat
hi`

Really dont how to. Hope someone will have the solution.

Comment: This really depends too much on the program to be answered without more detail. If the program is expecting to receive data from standard input, then typing `/chat` and then typing your input should work just fine. If it is expecting arguments, then you'll feed it arguments as SpyrosP suggests. If it is expecting a file, then you'll have to give it a file.

Comment: Are you looking for `echo something | ./chat` perhaps?

Comment: the program is just a simple chat, I can chat through the terminal.
the program is waiting for input.

but how can i give this input with bash?

Comment: @erik

i want to start the program, and then talk several of lines to the program.

Comment: @Tom: Then run the command that sends these lines (e.g. `cat textfile`) and pipe it to your program with `| ./chat`

Comment: ive tried "echo Hello, welcome! | echo Chat on! | ./chat"
but it doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
./chat << EOF
this is the input to chat
EOF
```

Comment: No.  You can do: ./chat << EOF<newline> everthing between that line and a line with EOF by itself will be the input.  If you want a single line, you can do : echo "Hello, welcome?" | ./chat

Comment: Since this is bash, there are also here-strings: `./chat <<< 'Hi, I'm a here-string'`

Answer (score 1):

what you are doing is right. make sure that the script is executable and it accepts command line parameters.

```
#! /bin/bash
echo Hi $1
```

> ./hi SO

o/p

> Hi SO

**EDIT :**

create a new text file with the content that you desire and then 
./chat < example.txt

Comment: wow, dont know if i understand.
i can do "./chat welcom on the chat" ?

Comment: that totally depends on the script, if the script that you are executing accepts command arguments, then it works for sure ..

Comment: the program is not relying on startup arguments.
when the program starts, its listening for input.
i want the bash file to start the program, and then send a message "Hello, welcome!"

Comment: heres a very simple way .. create a new file text file with Hello, welcome as content and then ./chat < example.txt

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly - you want to FIRST get some fixed text in
THEN you want to take input from the keyboard ...

IF thats all you want

```
cat  welcomeText.txt  - | ./chat
```

cat will concatenate your fixed text (welcomText.txt, a file)
it will then read from standard input ("`-`")

That will be piped ("`|`") into chat

There are more advanced ways of doing this by creating another file descriptor and selectively write to chat from various sources

Answer (score 0):

The input which you are going to type can be saved in some variable by using the following command:

```
read var
```

This would perform the work of scaning the whole input which you type after running the program and storing it in variable "var".

For eg:

Following code will read input and display the same:

```
read var 
echo $var
```

Answer (score -1):

This clarifies the bash commands about command line arguments :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo name of script is $0
echo first argument is $1
echo second argument is $2
echo seventeenth argument is $17
echo number of arguments is $#
```

Comment: I see, but how can I communicate with the program without using the arguments?

Comment: No, the seventeenth argument is `${17}`. If you do `$17`, you get the first argument followed by a literal "7".